# Best ways in which to conduct background tasks

Tags: php

Using PHP, I want to have scheduled tasks based upon the time the server is currently running.

Say at 7pm on Sunday I want a database query to be ran.

The way in which I've considered doing this is to put the task in the script that is ran on each page load in the session init.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with cron?

Answer (score 3):

One method to automatically run a PHP script at specified time intervals is to use Crontab. This can be particularly beneficial for scripts that need to automatically update information without user interaction such as a script that gathers website statistics so that they can be emailed to you or a script that regularly retrieves content from another website.

See: [PHP CLI and Cron](http://www.webpronews.com/php-cli-and-cron-2004-04)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cron to trigger your script for you with something like this:

If you have ssh access you can add a crontab entry like this:

```
crontab -e
```

and enter something like this:

```
0 19 * * 0 php -f /path/to/script/file.php
```

where 19 is the hour (7pm), 0th day of the week (sunday), and 0 is the minute.

this will run at 7pm on sunday.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) tab is for.  You can specify whatever tasks, scripts, or other programs you need to run at whatever time you want to run them.  Cron is run by your operating system and goes by your operating system's clock.

For example if I wanted to run a PHP script every minute, I would put something like the following into my cron tab.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

How you actually create cron entries depends on what your server setup is like.  If you have some sort of shell access on a Unix/Linux system, you can edit your cron tab easily by running the following command.

```
crontab -e
```

That will bring up the crontab in the default text editor.

If you are using something like cPanel, you will have to consult the manual for information on how to [edit cron entries](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs).

The actual syntax for the cron can be complicated at first.  There are [entry generators](http://www.csgnetwork.com/crongen.html) online that you can use if you need help.

```
0 * * * * php /some/script.php # This will execute at the 0 minute of every hour.
0 1 * * * php /some/script.php # This will execute at the 0 minute of the first hour of every day.  In other words, every day at 1AM.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your systems Cron deamon to schedule and run a PHP file.

First read up on Cron:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Then implement this:

Open crontab:

```
vim crontab -e
```

Add an entry to your cron table:

```
0 19 * * 0 /path/to/php /path/to/script.php
```

Your script.php will contain the code/logic to query the database.